# Identify network down on tcp socket using TCP_KEEPALIVE in C

Tags: c, sockets, visual-studio-2012, tcp, tcpsocket

I am writing a tcp client program that receives data from a tcp server. I am unable to close the connection when the network goes bad (i.e broken network).

I have used SO_KEEPALIVE to allow an application to enable keep-alive packets for a socket connection. The SO_KEEPALIVE property turns on successfuly but i am unable to modify the default value of KeepAliveTime (i.e 2 hrs)

The other avilable option to edit the KeepAliveTime was editing the registry value but i cannot find the registry key at the location **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters**

The following code checks and enables the SO_KEEPALIVE.

```
char optval;
char optout;
int optlen;
int optlen2;
optlen = sizeof(optval);
optlen2 = sizeof(optout);
got = getsockopt(loFds[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, &optlen );
if(got < 0) 
{
    printf("getsockopt unsuccessful. Error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else if (got == 0)  {
//printf("SO_KEEPALIVE is %s\n", (optval ? "ON" : "OFF"));
printf("SO_KEEPALIVE is %ld\n", optval);
}


optval = 1;
//optout = 1;
got = (setsockopt(loFds[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen));
 if( got < 0) 
 {
    printf("setsockopt unsuccessful on socket\n");
 }
 else if (got == 0)  {
     printf("SO_KEEPALIVE set on socket\n");
 }



got = (getsockopt(loFds[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optout, &optlen2 ));
if( got < 0) 
{

    printf("getsockopt unsuccessful. Error %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

}
else if (got == 0)  {
    printf("SO_KEEPALIVE is %ld\n", optval);
}
```

But i require it to disconnect the socket after a user defined time (may be 5min or so). Kindly suggest any other solution.

Platform: Visual C 2012 on Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Can you do it at the application level?  That is, use your own "heartbeat" messages to know if the connection dies?

Comment: Your code checks it twice. Why?

Comment: @JohnZwinck i am not sure how to use my own hearbeat meassages since its a multi threaded application and connects several sockets at the same time.

Comment: @EJP i wanted to know the default state of the socket therefore i check it before enabling it

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2000 and later, you can use [WSAIoctl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220.aspx) instead of `setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE)` to set custom keep-alive timeout/interval values on a per-socket basis.

You can also use [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx), [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540.aspx), or [`WSAEventSelect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576.aspx) to detect when data is available for reading, before then reading it.  If a timeout occurs before data arrives, simply close the socket.

Comment: @Remy..I have tried using  **WSAIoctl()** before but my environment does not seem to recognize the function. Do you have any idea why it would be behaving like that?

Comment: @SIA: `WSAIoctl()` is declared in `winsock2.h`, not `winsock.h`. And `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` is declared in `Mstcpip.h`.  Are you `#include`'ing those header files in your code? And linking to `Ws2_32.lib`/`Ws2_32.dll`?

Comment: yes you are right..i was using 'winsock.h' instead of 'winsock2.h'. I have now included 'winsock2.h' but my code is giving a lot of 'struct type redefinition' and 'redefinition; different linkage' errors. I am figuring them out now

Comment: I have excluded `winsock.h` and included `winsock2.h` but i still seem to get `'struct' type redefinition errors`. Any idea why would that be?

Comment: winsock.h and winsock2.h do NOT co-exist. Winsock2.h replaces winsock.h, but windows.h still includes winsock.h unless `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined. Otherwise, you can either include winsock2.h before windows.h, or add `_WINSOCKAPI_` to your project's global defines to disable winsock.h.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..that solved the problem. Defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `windows.h`

Answer (score 0):

Global definition:

```
struct tcp_keepalive alive;
DWORD dwBytesRet = 0;
```

Keep alive implementation starts from here:

```
alive.onoff = TRUE;             //keepalive enabled
alive.keepaliveinterval = 1000; //Interval between keepalive probes is set to 1 sec

alive.keepalivetime = 20000;    //Keep alive time set to 20 sec

if (WSAIoctl(loFds[i], SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &alive, sizeof(alive), NULL, 0,
&dwBytesRet, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) failed.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("WSAIotcl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS) Success.\n");
}
```